# How can I generate training data on the fly in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, on-the-fly

I want to create the Moving MNIST training set in TensorFlow. I've been thinking about creating a subclass of `tf.ReaderBase` and emitting `tf.Example` training sequences in `tf.ReaderBase.read` or using `tf.QueueBase`, but I am not sure whether this is the right way to approach it and whether it is a good idea in the first place (regarding CPU load for creating the sequences during training).